# Python for loop IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am somewhat new to python and I could use some help figuring out what my error entails.

```
datafile = "filename.csv"

colors = ['Green','White','Yellow','Pink','Blue','Purple','Gray','Brown','Orange','Red','Black']  # put in order of the columns

colnames = []
for color in colors:
    colnames.append(color+"1")
    colnames.append(color+"2")

# Define data structure to hold responses for each column
responses = dict()
for colname in colnames:
    responses[colname] = []

# Read in the responses
lines = open(datafile,"r").readlines()
for line in lines:
    data = line.strip('\n').split(",")
for i,colname in enumerate(colnames):
    if '1' in colname:
        responses[colname].append(data[i])
    else:
        responses[colname].append(data[i].split(','))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4039ddb1f5f5> in <module>()
     21             responses[colname].append(data[i])
     22         else:
---> 23             responses[colname].append(data[i].split(','))
     24 
     25 # Count the number of subjects

     IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not sure if the `IndexError: list index out of range` is from the actual `else:` or something is wrong with the `responses[colname].append(data[i].split(','))`.
It could also be in my `for` loop of the list `colnames`, I am fairly certain that aspect is correct, but you never know

Comment: When the error appears, it should give you a line number. Try looking at that and seeing what you find

Comment: seems like `data[i]` throws the index error

Comment: The index is probably for the data[i]. bascially you have more colors (x2 since you label it 1 and 2) then you have data elements

Comment: It means that you have lines in your file that do not have the required number of fields (commas).

Comment: I think it is because data is empty. If you try to access data[0] on an empty array it will give "IndexError: list index out of range". Check that there is anything in data by the time it gets to the else statement. You may need to declare data outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in lines:
    data = line.strip('\n').split(",")
```

I think the above code is why you got the `IndexError`,because the assignment to `data` will overwrite the previous one, and the content of `data` is always **the last line**. (Unless you just want the last line).

e.g:

**filename.csv**

```
blue,red
red,green
yellow,red
```

---

```
data=['yellow', 'red']
```

That means your `for` loop is equivalent to 
`data=lines[-1].strip('\n').split(",")`

So I suppose this is what you want:

```
data=[]
for line in lines:
    data.append(line.strip('\n').split(","))
```

Or use this list comprehension:

```
data=[line.strip('\n').split(",") for l in lines]
```

And then make sure that the length of `data` is greater than `colnames`.
By the way, try to debug your code, or `print` variables, you will find the reason.